# I have a mandatory check to be done with ngif but I have one more input value to be checked depending it being present or not

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

One mandatory condition has to be checked always and if one more value is present (having a particular value) then show else hide

I am trying the OR condition but it's not working.

1. My objective is for cond1 always it has to be checked
2. For cond2 only if cond2 is present and if it is present it has value === 'US' then it should evaluate to true (if cond2 has some different values then evaluate to false)
3. If cond2 is not present or undefined then only evaluate cond1(means cond1 has to be evaluated all the time)

ts

```
  @Input cond2
```

html

```
  <div *ngIf = "cond1 || cond2 && cond2 === "US">
    Display
  </div>
```

> Evaluate cond1 (always) and cond2 if present

Comment: try  <div *ngIf = "cond1 || (cond2 && cond2 === "US")>

Comment: Be careful of your inverted commas: `<div *ngIf = 'cond1 || cond2 && cond2 === "US"'>`

Answer (score 0):

To summarise, you want to return:

- true IF cond1 is true AND cond2 is undefined OR
- true IF cond1 is true AND cond2 === 'US'

So:

```
<div *ngIf="(cond1 && !cond2) || (cond1 && cond2 === 'US')">
```